# Rails ActiveRecord sanitize_sql replaces ? in string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a plain SQL query written by a trusted administrator that is to be run in a Rails (4.2) app. I am sanitizing it with `ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql, ...)` to allow user inputs to act as conditions, using the `?` character for bind variables. The code has to allow arbitrary SQL, so I'm not interested in the arguments about why this is not the Rails way, etc.

The problem is that I can not include `?` in a result field in the SQL without the underlying `replace_bind_variables` method replacing an intended literal `?` in the result.

A simple query for example would be:

```
select 'http://www.google.com?q=' || res from some_table where a = ?;
```

To sanitize:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql, [sql, 'not me'], :some_table)
```

The sanitization fails because the `?` in the URL gets replaced with the data intended for the condition, leading to the exception:

```
ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid: wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2)
```

The question is, does `sanitize_sql` or some variant allow literal `?` characters to be included in a query so that they are not replaced? Is there some way of escaping them?

Comment: try this https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/sanitize_sql_for_conditions/class

Comment: @wasipeer that is a reasonable enough answer, unfortunately it requires a lot of existing SQL to be reworked to replace arrays for use with a hash of conditions. Just using an existing array won't work, as the method `sanitize_sql_array` checks for ? in the statement and relies on ? as a bind character before using the %s approach.

Comment: Do you need to go through ActiveRecord for this or could you drop down a level and use real prepared statements where `'?'` would be just a string rather than a placeholder inside a string literal.

Comment: @muistooshort I don't follow what you mean. As long as the SQL can be written exactly as it is now (like the example above), then whatever handles the sanitization of supplied conditions and generates subsequent SQL is possibly fine. Can you provide some more details on what you are suggesting?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Postgres. Does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I read through the ActiveRecord source and couldn't identify a way to handle this situation without a lot of code changes. There doesn't appear to be a way to escape the `?` characters.

To resolve it for this one query I ended up using the SQL `chr()` function to generate a character that would pass the santization step untouched:

```
select 'http://www.google.com' || chr(63) || 'q=' || res from some_table where a = ?;
```

ASCII character 63 is `?`.

Although not a perfect solution, I could at least get this one SQL query into the system without having to make massive code changes.